# Warning in TextConnextion in R on unix

Tags: r, unix, stan

I am trying to pipe away some output from stan called from within R, but I get the weirdest error message on linux:

```
 capture.output ({fit <- rstan::stan(filename_temp,
                                      data = X,
                                      chains = chains,
                                      cores = ifelse(n_cores>=4,4,n_cores),
                                      init = init,
                                      iter = iter,
                                      verbose = F,
                                      warmup=warmup,
                                      refresh = refresh,
                                      thin = thin,
                                      pars=parameter_names,
                                      control = list(adapt_delta = acceptance_prob),
                                      ...)}, file = output_file,append=T)
```

throws `Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console`

The weirdest thing: This does not happen on R Studio Server with browser interface, where the OS is identical. I am happy to post a small reproducible code snippet, but hoping the answer is something obvious I am missing.

Comment: I think `rstan::stan()` and `rstan::sampling()` do not work due to some weird Rcpp thing. You have to first do `library(rstan)`.

Comment: The thing is, the above runs. I just want to get rid of the annoying warning above. It also ignores my refresh command, and there is no output at all until stan has run (which is desired). But, ideally I want refresh to work, and I would like that warning to go away to not scare people... Thx!